# Why does the LibSSH2 ssh2_exec example crash?

Tags: windows, crash, libssh2

I'm trying to get [the LibSSH2 ssh2_exec example](http://www.libssh2.org/examples/ssh2_exec.html) to work under windows but it crashes on the following line:

```
while ((rc = libssh2_session_handshake(session, sock)) == LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN);
```

The call is made ~1200 times before it crashes. What would be going wrong here?

I used [this guide](http://chaosstuff.com/2013/07/07/build-libssh2-on-visual-studio-2010/) to compile LibSSH2 if that makes a difference.

A bit more digging suggests the crash occurs in the `libssh2_sha1` function in the `EVP_DigestFinal(&ctx, out, NULL);` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried [a newer version of OpenSSH](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html), built by a different source and that solved the issue.